# Change the on-screen keyboard key size?

Tags: windows, keyboard, touchscreen

Is it possible to change the key size of the on-screen keyboard included with Windows XP?

I find it really difficult to use on a touch screen, when there is no keyboard available. I know you can the [change the font size](http://www.bltt.org/software/xposk/osk_xp.htm), but this does not change the key size.

[image: On-Screen Keyboard]

Comment: i suppose you can increase the DPI settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no maximize button is possible to maximize it. Here is the workaround - http://www.bltt.org/software/xposk/osk_xp.htm#resize_note

Answer (score 0):

YES.

The keyboard is just a window.

Select and drag an edge or a corner and you can make the keyboard window any size, the keys will change size as the window size changes.